# dontnetcore error on creating a angular component

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I get the following error when trying to create an angular module inside angular component directory which is the project I created using following yo

[2](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) yo generator-aspnetcore-spa

Following is the error

> Error locating module for declaration
>
> SilentError: No module files found

Created File structure is as below.

[image]

Comment: Have you set the base href in your root file (ex: index.html). Without this my angular files for directives can't be found. Here's how I do it in .Net <base href="<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>" />

Comment: Didn't work for me but I found a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Following workaround fixed this issue

Rename app.client.module to **app.client.module** .